# Simple GAS assembly program to print out all of the command line arguments provided to it

Tags: assembly

Although I've used assembly quite a bit for some simply things, I feel like I've never properly learnt how to write it idiomatically, by which I mean: which variables to use where, how best to structure loops and conditionals, how best/when to preserve registers over procedure calls, etc...

I wrote a small program which interfaces with the C standard library runtime, and will simply print the the amount of command line arguments followed by a list of all those arguments, for example:

```
$ ./sver Hello, this is a test!
The (6) arguments:
./sver
Hello,
this
is
a
test!
```

And here's the code itself:

```
    .global main
    .type main, @function

main:
    mov    %rsi, %r12

    mov    %rdi, %rsi
    lea    message(%rip), %rdi
    xor    %rax, %rax
    pushq  %rsi
    call   printf
    popq   %rsi


loop:
    cmp    $0, %rsi # If we've printed everything, then finish
    jz end

    mov    0(%r12), %rdi # Dereference r12 to get the current arg
    pushq  %rsi
    call   puts # Print one argument
    popq   %rsi

    add    $8, %r12 # Advance r12 to point at the next arg
    dec    %rsi
    jmp    loop
end:
    mov    $0, %eax
    ret

    .section .data
message:
    .string "The (%u) arguments:\n"

# Explicitly say that I don't want an executable stack, otherwise GCC complains
.section .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

I'm compiling this with GCC.

Some aspects specifically that I'm unsure about:

- I'm using R12 to store a copy of RSI (which is just `argv` from C). I use it later when iterating to print all the arguments. However I feel like something about this is weird - is there a more idiomatic way of doing this?
- Before/after calls to `printf` and `puts` I need to preserve the value of RSI, since I use it as the argument counter. To do this I push/pop it from the stack, but perhaps it would be better to store it in some callee-saved register instead? But it still specifically has to be in RSI for printf to work, at least...

I tried writing a functionally equivalent program in C to look at its compiled assembly, but it's pretty incomprehensible, with lots of seemingly unnecessary jumping around etc.

I think my main problem is that I often don't know which register I should use to store a given value, or whether I should even put it on the stack.

Thanks!

Comment: I understand that _compilers_ output lines like "_xor    %rax, %rax_" when they want zero. But for humans, don't we have like a "clear rax" mnemonic, a macro? // Anyway, thank you for the `# comments`, they're lovely, as are the symbolic labels. And please _do_ offer a tag or Review Context that explains the particular processors you intend this code should run on. If you viewed the corresponding C code through the lens of https://godbolt.org, it wouldn't hurt to mention a link in your Question.

Comment: Thanks for the comments @J_H
I see your point about `xor %rax, %rax` potentially not being as clear as it could be, however from what I've seen it seems pretty common in handwritten assembly - perhaps a macro would be nice though!
And yes, I'm surprised I didn't mention the processor this will run on; it's for x86-64, btw.
For viewing the corresponding C code's assembly, I actually used `gcc -S`, so it wasn't so easy to link unfortunately.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> mov    $0, %eax
> xor    %rax, %rax
> ```

The efficient way to zero a 64-bit register is to `xor` the register to itself, and because any writing to a 32-bit register will automatically zero the upper dword, it is best to `xor` the 32-bit version of the register to itself: `xor %eax, %eax`.
Using `xor %rax, %rax` requires a REX prefix byte while `xor %eax, %eax` does not. Shorter code is generally better.
The `mov $0, %eax` instruction has an even longer encoding and you should only use it in cases where you don't want flags modified.

> ```
> cmp    $0, %rsi
> jz end
> ```

The efficient way to find out if a 64-bit register is 0, is to `test` the register to itself. Here you would write `test %rsi, %rsi` followed by `jz end`. Following a `cmp` (like you were doing), it would have been more idiomatic to write `je end`. Both `jz` and `je` have the same encoding but `je` better conveys the meaning of two items being '**e**qual' to each other.

> ```
> pushq  %rsi
> call   printf
> popq   %rsi
> ...
> pushq  %rsi
> call   puts
> popq   %rsi
> ```

> Before/after calls to `printf` and `puts` I need to preserve the value of RSI, since I use it as the argument counter. To do this I push/pop it from the stack, but perhaps it would be better to store it in some callee-saved register instead? But it still specifically has to be in RSI for printf to work, at least...

The `%rsi` register is a so-called **call-clobbered** register, see this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56178078). So these *printf* and *puts* functions are allowed to use `%rsi` for their own purposes and leave it changed. That's why you had to preserve the register yourself. You can easily escape from this simply by choosing a **call-preserved** register instead. I would suggest you pick `%rbx` for your loop control variable.

> ```
> loop:
>   cmp    $0, %rsi # If we've printed everything, then finish
>   jz end
>   ...
>   dec    %rsi
>   jmp    loop
> end:
> ```

An efficient loop tries to minimize the number of control transferring instructions (here `jz` and `jmp`), and prefers to put the loop condition's logic at the bottom of the loop. Remember that the `dec` instruction already defines a number of flags, including the ZF (zero flag), therefore you could replace the unconditional `jmp loop` by the conditional `jnz loop`. Of course, you would then also move the initial test-for-zero to outside of the loop.

All of the above in one code snippet:

```
main:
    mov    %rdi, %rbx    # argc
    mov    %rsi, %r12    # argv

    lea    message(%rip), %rdi
    mov    %rbx, %rsi
    xor    %eax, %eax
    call   printf

    test   %rbx, %rbx
    jz     end
next:
    mov    0(%r12), %rdi # Dereference r12 to get the current arg
    call   puts
    add    $8, %r12      # Advance r12 to point at the next arg
    dec    %rbx
    jnz    next
end:

    xor    %eax, %eax
    ret
```

Isn't *argc* always at least one? The initial test-for-zero seems not necessary then. And also, *argc* will be a small number, so we can write the shorter `mov %edi, %ebx`, `mov %ebx, %esi`, and `dec %ebx` instructions instead:

```
main:
    mov    %edi, %ebx    # argc
    mov    %rsi, %r12    # argv

    lea    message(%rip), %rdi
    mov    %ebx, %esi
    xor    %eax, %eax
    call   printf

next:
    mov    0(%r12), %rdi # Dereference r12 to get the current arg
    call   puts
    add    $8, %r12      # Advance r12 to point at the next arg
    dec    %ebx
    jnz    next

    xor    %eax, %eax
    ret
```